# shopping cart, matter with quantity

Tags: php, product-quantity

this is a shoping cart is work kind of fine but the matter is with quantity, when the quantity is 1 i like got the single_price automatically any sugestion:

```
$global = 0;

if(isset($_POST['update_cart'])){
    if(isset($_POST['qty'.$i])){
        $qty = $_POST['qty'.$i];
    }else{
        $qty+=1;    
    }

    $update_qty = "update cart set qty='$qty'";

    $run_qty = mysqli_query($con, $update_qty); 

    $_SESSION['qty']=$qty;



    $global = $global+ ($single_price*$qty); 


    $total =$total + ($values * $qty);


}
```

Comment: when i click to update_cart is work fine but i like got just the price for one product with out i click in update cart; help please

Answer (score 0):

I see a problem with the concat replace this :

```
$update_qty = "update cart set qty='$qty'";
```

With this :

```
$update_qty = "update cart set qty='".$qty."';
```

Comment: when i do what u say they show me a wrong message syntax error, unexpected '"'"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\cart.php on line 130

Comment: all work fine just i want have the price for one product automatiquelly without i click in update cart

Comment: Oops it was that : 
$update_qty = "update cart set qty='".$qty."';